# Function returing undefined tweets

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am attempting to return tweets given predefined search criteria, with the variables simply being used as placeholder for the example. The issue is that the variables tweets and profiles return 'undefined' when the code is run. I am unsure why this is instead of 'object object', any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
var count = 10,
    profile = 'manutd',
    date = '2011-11-11',
    keyword = 'man city',
    lan = 'en',
    search = keyword + " since:" + date + " lang:" + lan;

var tweets = getTweets();
var profiles = getProfile();
console.log('Started')

function handleTweets(err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.error('Get error', err)
  }  
  else {
    console.log('Get Tweets');
    console.log(tweets);
    console.log('Finished');
  }
}

function handleFriends(err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.error('Get error', err)
  }  
  else {
    console.log('Get Friends');
    console.log(profiles);
    console.log('Finished');
  }
}

function getTweets(){
  client.get('search/tweets', { q: search, count: count, from: profile },
              handleTweets)
}

function getProfile( callback ){
  client.get('friends/list', { screen_name: profile, count: count },
             handleFriends)
}
```

Comment: You missed `return` in functions `getTweets()` & `getProfile()`;

Comment: Ah my bad, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var count = 10,
profile = 'manutd',
date = '2011-11-11',
keyword = 'man city',
lan = 'en',
search = keyword + " since:" + date + " lang:" + lan;

console.log('Started')

function handleTweets(err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.error('Get error', err)
  } else {
    console.log('Get Tweets');
    console.log(data);
    console.log('Finished');
  } 
}

function handleFriends(err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.error('Get error', err)
  } else {
    console.log('Get Friends');
    console.log(data);
    console.log('Finished');
  }
}

function getTweets(){
  client.get('search/tweets', { q: search, count: count, from: profile },
          handleTweets)
}

function getProfile( callback ){
  client.get('friends/list', { screen_name: profile, count: count },
         handleFriends)
}
```

Here you are accessing undefined properties `tweets` & `profiles` in callback function that's why you are getting `undefined` not the data returned by api ;)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I have corrected this and It is now returning Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }

Comment: @cockmagic Where you set base api url as you directly used `friends/list` & `search/tweets`;

Comment: I'm sorry im not sure I follow, so in order to return the tweets the 'friends/list' and 'search/tweets' need to be changed?

Comment: May you define what is `client`

Comment: Client is the twit instance with the auth keys etc

Comment: @cockmagic i have updated my answer this was my mistake now copy and paste this code as it is;

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated